# How to stack AlertDialog buttons vertically?

Tags: java, android

I am using builder to create `AlertDialogs` in Android using the pattern:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

builder.setTitle(...);
builder.setMessage(...);

builder.setPositiveButton(button1Text, ...);
builder.setNeutralButton(button2Text, ...);
builder.setNegativeButton(button3Text, ...);

builder.show();
```

Currently, only two of the buttons are displayed, because the buttons are too wide to fit in the dialog. How can I enforce the buttons to stack vertically?

I am using the `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert` theme, which uses `ButtonBarLayout` to build the buttons. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35059788/3946177), `ButtonBarLayout` can stack wide buttons vertically automatically, when its `mAllowStacking` property is set, but it seems to default to false in my case. Is there a way I can set it to true when I build the `AlertDialog`?

Comment: Android decides the position of the buttons in AlertDialog.  If you need something different, you will have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that with an `AlertDialog` . You should create a custom `Dialog`, and implement that yourself. Something like this would do it

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
dialog.setTitle(...);
dialog.setMessage(...);
dialog.show();
```

and your layout `dialog_layout.xml` should be something like

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              orientation="vertical">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this now but can't figure out how to dismiss the dialog from the button listeners.  The view (and listeners) are created before the dialog is built so I haven't figured out how to dismiss it.

Comment: How do you add an OnClick listener to these?

Answer (score 8):

I don't prefer hacks. But this strikes me immediately.

> If the button text it too long to all fit horizontally, then it will
>   automatically get laid out in a vertical column of three buttons.

Just make the button text long.

```
  builder.setPositiveButton("          Yes", { dialog, _ -> {} })
  builder.setNeutralButton("          May be", { dialog, _ -> {} })
  builder.setNegativeButton("          No", { dialog, _ -> {} })
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me fix this madness :)

Comment: this makes the button onclick highlighting very long

Comment: Padding with spaces is a really bad idea here and you're not really sure what you're going to get on the current flavor of Android.  Ideally the OS version that you're using has done is a specific way, and if you try to fudge it with spaces you're going to run into problems at some point and have unpredictable results.  Also, it's likely that the UI just won't match the apps that were written correctly.

Comment: I agree with all of you.

Answer (score 6):

What if you did the alert box as a list?

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color)
           .setItems(R.array.colors_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Example taken from here (under adding a list): https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Then just take those list options and turn them into what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with MaterialAlertDialog as well.

I tried many solutions, but I think the best one is to override the button layout that material dialogs use. Copy paste the content of `mtrl_alert_dialog_actions.xml` from the material library and do the necessary changes. For example change the `ButtonBarLayout` to a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
    style="?attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollIndicators="top|bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@android:id/button1"
            style="?attr/buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@android:id/button2"
            style="?attr/buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@android:id/button3"
            style="?attr/buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Then override the layout by adding it to `res/values/refs.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item name="mtrl_alert_dialog_actions" type="layout" tools:override="true">@layout/mtrl_alert_dialog_actions_custom</item>
</resources>
```